# summation between items when the array in split

Tags: arrays, vb.net, split

If I have

```
Dim jmlBobot As Double = 0
    Dim hasil As String = "0000300005300113000000000000000000000"
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
       Dim bobot() As String = Split(hasil, "0")
        For j = 0 To bobot.Length - 1
            jmlBobot = jmlBobot + CDbl(Val(bobot(j)))
        Next
        ListView1.Items.Add(jmlBobot)
    Next
```

how summation between items and add to listview? because the sum is not suitable should amount to just 16. but in the listview item add 169, 338, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LINQ to do the sum to obtain the desired value of '16':

```
Dim hasil As String = "0000300005300113000000000000000000000"
Dim sum As Integer = (From s As String In hasil.Replace("0"c, "") Select CInt(s)).Sum

ListView1.Items.Add(sum.ToString)
```

...If I understood good that is what you are trying to do.